# PHP/mySQL select query compare time & limit query to only those within 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a script to select milestones from the DB that are only within 5 minutes (or any other set time amount) of the query. I'm having a few problems.

1. The dates are stored in the database in this format:

   example: 2016-12-05 21:19:00
2. when I run this query:

   SELECT * FROM milestones WHERE status="planned" and time >= NOW()

I am able to get the results for everything in the future, but how would I go about limiting the query to say only 5 minutes for example.

Comment: between now() and now() + interval 5 minute

Comment: so time >= NOW() +300 ?

Comment: Using `INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` is a lot more self-explanatory than 300, especially when you're talking days and weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` and `DATE_ADD` MySQL functions to achieve the desired result, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM milestones 
WHERE status="planned" and time BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

This would print all the entries having date between current date and next 5 minutes.

If you want to print the same for last 5 minutes, you can use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM milestones 
WHERE status="planned" and time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

Here's MySQL's documentation for [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) and [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: @Strawberry I have changed the answer and used `date_sub` if that's what you meant :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by the above query.